# Python: removing jpg files without matching txt files

Tags: files, python

I kindly ask for guidance or support on how to approach coding a Python script to remove .jpg images without.txt files. Presently, I have a `train` folder with folders `images` and `labels`. I am planning to put the images and their matching txt files in a directory. There are 70000 images and 69863 txt files with labels. I need to remove those images without their matching txt files, so I can have the same number of images as well as txt files. That is 69863 images matching those 69863 txt files.

An example is as follows: the image `0b911639-98f93d75.jpg` has its txt file `0b911639-98f93d75.txt`. However, some images have missing txt files. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I've created dirs tree like this:

```
.
├── images
│   ├── 1.jpg
│   ├── 2.jpg
│   ├── 3.jpg
│   ├── 4.jpg
│   └── 5.jpg
└── labels
    ├── 1.txt
    ├── 2.txt
    └── 5.txt
```

Easiest way to do it:

```
from os import listdir, remove
labels = listdir('labels')
images = listdir('images')
for image in images:
 if '{}.{}'.format(image.split('.')[0], 'txt') not in labels:
  print('Going to remove %s' % image)
  remove('images/%s' % image)
```

Comment: Thank you! I will let you know the results later.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a simple for loop from within the images folder:

```
cd images
for f in *.jpg; do [ -f "../labels/${f%.*}.txt" ] || echo rm "$f"; done
```

Remove the `echo` if you're happy with the output.